# Light therapy: allowed or not?

Tags: halal-haram, medical

I wanted to ask if the use of Light Therapy (Red) is allowed. I have not found anything that says if it's allowed to use in Islam. There has been extensive scientific research on it and light therapy it has proven to have positive benefits on health problems/ailments like eczema, rosacea, thyroid problem, back pain, arthritis, ageing skin, hair loss, wound healing  etc. It is said to have no side effects and the treatment is performed by having the light shone exteriorly on the area to be treated for 5 to 20 minutes, multiple sessions might be needed. It allows the cells to repair more quickly. Can I use it?

Comment: The default answer to "is X allowed" is "if you have no reason to think that it is haram, then go ahead".

Comment: Salam and welcome on Islam stack exchange the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider taking our 2 min. [tour] and visit our [help] to learn more about the site. Why are you checking whether something is allowed instead of the opposite? There's a rule in fiqh saying "anything is halal unless there's a clear evidence" not the contrary!

Answer (score 1):

There is a topic about it on the link below.

> https://islamqa.info/en/2438
>
> Generally speaking, medical treatment or seeking a cure is allowed,
> because of the report of Abu’l-Darda’ (may Allaah be pleased with him)
> who said: “The Messenger of Allaah (peace and blessings of Allaah be
> upon him) said: ‘Allaah has sent down the disease and the cure, and
> has made for every disease the cure. So treat sickness, but do not use
> anything haraam’” (Reported by Abu Dawood, 3376), and the hadeeth of
> Usaamah ibn Shurayk (may Allaah be pleased with him) who said: ‘The
> Bedouin said, “O Messenger of Allaah, should we not treat sickness?”
> He said: “Treat sickness, for Allaah has not created any disease
> except He has also created the cure, except for one disease.” They
> said, “O Messenger of Allaah, what is it?” He said: “Old age.”’”
> (Reported by al-Tirmidhi, 4/383, no. 1961. He said: This is a saheeh
> hasan hadeeth. See also Saheeh al-Jaami’, 2930).

But also a reminder that whatever benefit you gain from any treatment is by the permission of Allah(swt) and prevention of disease also is made by the permission of Allah(swt).

So in general even thought doing certain thing can benefit us we acknowledge that it is by the will of Allah(swt) that he made it possible.

So if you seek something which will benefit and not cause harm to you based on knowledge than you should seek that which is good and lawful. If thought knowledge comes your way that this practice is in fact more armful then beneficial than you should stop the practice.

> Allahu Alim